# Intercepting https request from a Dart program

Tags: dart, mitmproxy

I want to debug a Dart program which makes https request  to an API with the [http library of Dart](https://pub.dev/packages/http). So i want to intercept all the input and output https GET/POST. For that I use a [man in the middle proxy](https://mitmproxy.org/). The proxy works and i can see all the http and https traffic of various applications in my laptop. But I can't see the one of my dart program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use flutter [DevTools](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/devtools/overview), it has a networking tab that shows all of your app networking activity.